# Add onclick event to a div

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick

I have a dynamically generated button as below:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 150px; cursor: pointer;" id="thebutton"  class="orange_form">
            <span style="padding-top: 17px; font-size: 1.5em;">The button</span>
        </div>
```

To display the button I have this code inside of javascript:

```
$('div#thebutton').click(function() {
        $('div#Form').show();
        $.scrollTo($('div#Form'), 800);
    });
```

I want to add GA event tracking to this button:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'label']);"
```

Is this correct?

```
$('div#thebutton').click(function() {
        $('div#Form').show();
        $.scrollTo($('div#Form'), 800);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'label']);
    });
```

Or should I create a different script to call this function?

```
$('div#thebutton').click(function() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'label']);
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind re-wording the question title? It doesn't match the question content.

Comment: Looks fine. Have you tried it? Off topic: Using the element type in your selector is unnecessary and reduces efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

the "onClick" element in the button tag will cause the function specified on the other side of the equal sign to be called: "onClick"="foo()" will call function "Foo" when the button is clicked.  If you want to run "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'label']);" then put that in the function that you specify for the "onClick" element.

Comment: What? I can't see something you're seeing? Where in the `button` tag there's an `onclick` event handler?